# Why is Pacific Beach, San Diego County specified in CA PRC §14571.4

Tags: statutes

CA PRC §14570 - 14575.1 addresses the RETURNS portion of the CALIFORNIA BEVERAGE CONTAINER RECYCLING AND LITTER REDUCTION ACT. Throughout the statute is generic for the state until §14571.4 where it identifies specific requirements for Pacific Beach, San Diego County, CA.

Why would the law have this special provision?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about "why" a law is the way it is are generally political rather than legal. Try the politics stack.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the statute](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/public-resources-code/prc-sect-14571-4.html) it appears that the State Government in California is engaged in a pilot project in Pacific Beach to see if a different approach than they usually use to handling this issue works better than the status quo, without disrupting the rest of the state if it turns out that the pilot project approach is a flop that doesn't work well.